# Is there any way to change fringe size for a window only in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

When I change fringes in emacs using

```
 (set-fringe-mode 0)
```

It affects all windows. Is there any way of changing the fringe size only for one window? I want to change the fringe depending on the mode of the window I'm working on (let's say one fringe for windows that have code and another one for editing markdown) and I've not been able to do so at the moment.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `set-window-fringes` lets you customize the fringes of a particular window:

```
(set-window-fringes (selected-window) 0 0)
```

This sets the width of both the left and the right fringe of the current window to `0` pixels. You can change the values to suit your needs (the first numeric argument controls the width of the left fringe, the second numeric arguments controls the width of the right fringe).

You can wrap the call to `set-window-fringes` in a function and add that function to the hook(s) of the modes for which you want to customize the fringe:

```lisp
(defun hide-fringes ()
  (set-window-fringes (selected-window) 0 0))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'hide-fringes)
```

Note that you can use a `lambda` function for this purpose as well (as @Dan suggests) but when adding custom code to hooks it is good practice to wrap it in a function in order to be able to easily *remove* it from the hook again (via `remove-hook`).

Comment: Woops!  Must have been writing my answer when you posted your original.  @Rafa: please accept @itsjeyd's answer.  By the way: the first argument `nil` defaults to the selected window.

Comment: @Dan Yes, I think that's what happened, you were a couple minutes behind me. Thanks for being a good sport!! Maybe we should start collaborating on CW answers to Emacs questions... ;)

Comment: Of course!  This place is awesome when people are friendly.

Answer (score 0):

`set-window-fringes` will do it on a buffer-local basis, so put a call to it in the mode initiation hook along the lines of `(set-window-fringes nil 8 8)`, where the 8s (or whatever you like) refer to the pixel width on the left and right.  So, e.g. for text mode:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-window-fringes nil 8 8)))
```